# Emacs word wrap not working in horizontal split mode

Tags: emacs

I am looking at some C++ code and when using horizontal split screen toggle-truncate lines does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For narrow windows, Emacs takes the value of the variable `truncate-partial-width-windows` into account.  By default, it truncates windows that are narrower than 50 characters, but you can set it to always truncate horizontally split windows (`t`), or set it to `nil` to respect the value of `truncate-lines` (which `toggle-truncate` modifies).